# Synonym request: brightness, screen-brightness

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

- [screen-brightness](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-brightness) has 23 questions
- [brightness](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brightness) has 1 question

Comment: Maybe `brightness` was not intended for the screen, but for the one looking at it? #D

Comment: @Izzy I see what you did there.

Comment: Heh? Looks like the tag doesn't fit me, I don't get it :D Was no critics, just a joke (and a +1 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, edited the brightness-tagged question and created synonym.